# Erlang: when to perform `inets:start()`?

Tags: erlang, inets

What is the appropriate place for performing `inets:start()` ?

1. in `applicationname_app' module?
2. in `applicationname_sup` supervisor module?
3. in a child process hanging from the supervisor?\
4. someplace else?

(I am still struggling with `inets:httpd`)

**Note**: the answer cannot be to the tune " use a boot file " , please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inets is a "stand-alone" Erlang application; `inets:start()` is just an alias to `application:start(inets)`. I guess the answer pretty much depends on how you maintain your code.

If your code is packaged as an [application](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html), your .app file should list `inets` as  required to be started before yours (see the applications tag). Starting your applicaion with `application:start(my_app).` will now ensure that inets is also started. Consequence: if you make a boot file, it will also start inets for you :-P

If you are keen on not using applications, I guess the choice depends on how your code works. If you will always need inets to be started, it is better started by any of your supervisors. If it is rarely needed, you can always make sure it is started with something like:

```
ensure_app_started(App) ->
  case application:started(App) of
    ok -> ok;
    {error, already_started} -> ok;
    Error -> Error
  end.
```

Comment: @zed: thanks again. Let's say I were to package my app as an `application`, how would I start it from the command line? (I am mostly doing daemons).

Comment: @zed: i.e. `erl -sname daemon -detached -boot start_sasl -s daemon_app start`?  Show me an example, please.

Comment: Add SASL to the application dependencies as well. Make a release file, and then a boot script. Then -boot my_boot.

Comment: @Zed: I finally decided to restructure and go OTP all the way (almost- no boot files!). I went for a proper `.app` based structure. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In 2019, we use `rebar3` to [create an application](https://www.rebar3.org/docs/basic-usage#section-new-app-or-release) and manage its dependencies.  For dependencies that need to be downloaded, you add them to `rebar.config`, and `rebar3` will download the dependencies.  For example, if you add `hackney` (an http client) to rebar.config:

```
{erl_opts, [debug_info]}.
{deps, [
  {hackney, ".*", {git, "git://github.com/benoitc/hackney.git", {branch, "master"}}}
]}.

{shell, [
  % {config, "config/sys.config"},
    {apps, [http_client]}
]}.
```

Then do:

```
../your_app_name$ rebar3 compile
```

`rebar3` will download `hackney` and compile all the files in the `application`.

To make sure that all your dependencies get started before your app, you add the names of the dependencies to:

```
src/your_app_name.app.src
```

For instance,

```
{application, http_client,
 [{description, "An OTP application"},
  {vsn, "0.1.0"},
  {registered, []},
  {mod, {http_client_app, []}},
  {applications,
   [kernel,
    stdlib,
    hackney    %%%<=========HERE
   ]},
  {env,[]},
  {modules, []},

  {licenses, ["Apache 2.0"]},
  {links, []}
 ]}.
```

The actual .app file gets created here:

```
_build/default/lib/your_app_name/ebin/your_app_name.app
```

To start your app in the shell along with all its dependencies, you do:

```
../your_app_name$ rebar3 shell
```

The `inets` application comes with erlang, so it doesn't need to be downloaded, so you don't specify inets as a dependency in rebar.config (you'll get an error when you `$ rebar3 compile`).  You still need to specify inets as a dependency in your `application` in the file:

```
src/your_app_name.app.src
```

But `rebar3` itself uses `inets` (to download your dependencies), so even if you didn't specify `inets` as a dependency in your application, `inets` would still get started before your app.  You can test that by not specifying `inets` as a dependency in your `application`, then doing:

```
$ rebar3 shell
...
...
1> application:start(inets)
{error,{already_started,inets}}
```

But, don't rely on that and DO specify `inets` as a dependency in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is packaged as an [application](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html), list `inets` in the application resource file:

```
% Filename: ebin/flamingo.app
{application, flamingo,
  [{vsn, "1.0.0"},
   {modules, [flamingo_app,
              flamingo_sup,
              flamingo]},
   {applications, [kernel,
                   stdlib,
                   inets]},
   {mod, {flamingo_app, []}}
  ]}.
```

Then you can start the application using [`application:ensure_all_started(flamingo)`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#ensure_all_started-1). This ensures that inets is started automatically for you (i.e. there is no need to explicitly call `inets:start()`).

For example (assuming the *.app file and *.beam files and are in `ebin/`):

```
$ erl -pa ebin/
Eshell V9.2  (abort with ^G)
1> application:ensure_all_started(flamingo).
{ok,[inets,flamingo]}
```