# How to configure httpc profiles with rebar3?

Tags: erlang, rebar3

How can I set configuration options for [httpc](http://erlang.org/doc/man/httpc.html)'s profiles when using rebar3?

Here is the only [example](http://dudefrommangalore.blogspot.ca/2010/01/http-request-pipeline-in-erlang.html) being via `erl -config inets.config` that looks like this:

```
[{inets, 
[{services,[{httpc,[{profile, server1}]},
            {httpc, [{profile, server2}]}]}]
}].
```

I tried adopting it to my rebar3 project structure.

### Code

Project was created with rebar3, with standard OTP layout:

```
rebar3 new release myapp
```

Here is my `myapp/config/sys.config`:

```
[
  { myapp, []},
  {inets, [{services, [{httpc, [{profile, myapp}]}]}]}
].
```

`rebar.config`:

```
{erl_opts, [debug_info]}.
{deps, []}.

{relx, [{release, { myapp, "0.1.0" },
         [myapp,
          sasl]},

        {sys_config, "./config/sys.config"},
        {vm_args, "./config/vm.args"},

        {dev_mode, true},
        {include_erts, false},

        {extended_start_script, true}]
}.

{profiles, [{prod, [{relx, [{dev_mode, false},
                            {include_erts, true}]}]
            }]
}.
```

Here is my `myapp.app.src` file for completeness:

```
{application, myapp,
 [{description, "An OTP application"},
  {vsn, "0.1.0"},
  {registered, []},
  {mod, { myapp_app, []}},
  {applications,
   [kernel,
    stdlib
   ]},
  {env,[]},
  {modules, []},

  {maintainers, []},
  {licenses, []},
  {links, []}
 ]}.
```

### Requests

Here is a request I'm trying to make from rebar`s shell:

```
$ ./rebar3 shell
1> ===> Booted myapp
1> ===> Booted sasl
...
1> httpc:request( "http://reddit.com", myapp).
** exception exit: {noproc,
                    {gen_server,call,
                     [httpc_myapp,
                      {request,
                       {request,undefined,<0.88.0>,0,http,
                        {"reddit.com",80},
                        "/",[],get,
                        {http_request_h,undefined,"keep-alive",undefined,
                         undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                         undefined,...},
                        {[],[]},
                        {http_options,"HTTP/1.1",infinity,true,
                         {essl,[]},
                         undefined,false,infinity,...},
                        "http://reddit.com",[],none,[],1478280329839,
                        undefined,undefined,false}},
                      infinity]}}
     in function  gen_server:call/3 (gen_server.erl, line 212)
     in call from httpc:handle_request/9 (httpc.erl, line 574)
```

Here is the request *without* a profile, to check that inets actually works:

```
2> httpc:request( "http://reddit.com").

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 4-Nov-2016::13:25:51 ===
          supervisor: {local,inet_gethost_native_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.107.0>},{mfa,{inet_gethost_native,init,[[]]}}]

=PROGRESS REPORT==== 4-Nov-2016::13:25:51 ===
          supervisor: {local,kernel_safe_sup}
             started: [{pid,<0.106.0>},
                       {id,inet_gethost_native_sup},
                       {mfargs,{inet_gethost_native,start_link,[]}},
                       {restart_type,temporary},
                       {shutdown,1000},
                       {child_type,worker}]
{ok,{{"HTTP/1.1",200,"OK"},...
```

Comment: please show your `rebar.config`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

rebar3 itself use inets http clients so when It starts your application in shell, inets is already started and configured.  One workaround would be stop inets before your application starts, [as It's suggested by rebar3 developer](https://www.rebar3.org/discuss/56fe236ed393740e0080f407) (copied below).  Another one would be boot your release in console mode:

```
./_build/default/rel/myapp/bin/myapp console
```

Beside that there is another problem with your project.  You have not told you want inets being started for you.  You should have this line in `myapp.src`:

```
{applications, [kernel, stdlib, inets]}
```

Or you can list inets in `rebar.config` release section, to tell relx this app should be included in release and started on boot.

```
{relx, [{release, { myapp, "0.1.0" }, [inets, myapp, sasl]} ]}
```

## Stop Inets from Loading on rebar3 shell startup

Here is the copy of the [full answer](https://www.rebar3.org/discuss/56fe236ed393740e0080f407) by Fred Hebert from the rebar3 mailing list:

> We do need inets for package fetching and will likely not turn it off
>   automatically for all use cases as this could compromise general usage
>   of the rebar3 agent in case where the user application does not use
>   inets, but still asks to fetch packages in a subsequent run. The
>   workaround I would suggest would be to use a hook script for it. Hook
>   scripts run before we boot user applications and are regular escripts:
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env escript 
> main(_) -> application:stop(inets).
> ```
>
> You can then hook the script in with:
>
> ```
> {shell, [{script_file, "path/to/file"}]}
> ```
>
> in rebar3.config, or with
>
> ```
> rebar3 shell --script_file test/check_env.escript
> ```

Comment: Thank you. You were right about inets starting automatically with the rebar3 shell! Doing the little trick in the link helped.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything in the documentation to suggest that `rebar.config` can contain the application configuration you want.

Instead, application configuration is often kept in a configuration directory in your application, and like the example you gave says, you must use the `-config` flag when launching `erl` to point to the configuration file.

If you use rebar3 for [making release](http://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases) and start your service by [script made with relx](http://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases#booting-upgrade-and-inspecting) (from `_build/default/rel/<release_name>/bin/<release_name>` by default) the application configuration file is passed to `erl` for you.  If config file exist in your application directory, by default in `config/sys.config`, It will be regarded as application configuration, otherwise an empty configuration will be made.  You can customize Its path by [relax' release option](https://github.com/erlware/relx/wiki/configuration) `sys_config`.

For our software, we typically had a single `config/sys.config` file. The structure is the same as the config sample you have provided. Note that the configuration file can contain settings for many different services. For example, mixing inets with one of ours:

```
[{inets, [
     {services,[{httpc,[{profile, server1}]},
     {httpc, [{profile, server2}]}]}
 ]},
 {my_app, [
     {my_setting, "my value"}
 ]}
].
```

We launch with `erl -config config/sys.config`.
This way if we need to set service configuration we can simply update our configuration file, which also houses the configuration specific to this application.

As far as I'm aware, this is the correct method to use. I have not been able to find documentation supporting any other way of doing this.

Comment: Don't know who downvoted this. Sorry mate. Thanks for suggestion, but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: Reith has expanded on the answer. Perhaps now it helps out more? (Thanks Reith!)

Comment: Still doesn't work. I'm getting `noproc` when I try to issue a `httpc:request` with the `myapp` profile. I tried the `httpc` entry standalone like you suggested as well.

Comment: You need to start the inets process using `inets:start().` If you wish to use SSL, you also need to do `ssl:start().` Then you can make `httpc` requests. Note that this can be accomplished automatically if you add it to your `.app` profile. See [this StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839862/erlang-when-to-perform-inetsstart) question for more info on doing that.

Comment: The issue was the rebar3 shell starting inets automatically. See accepted answer. Thanks for looking into this anyways!